How to return failed ECS Fargate tasks logs to Step function
I am trying to orchestrate a pipeline in Step Functions with the components of Lambda and ECS:

Start -> Lambda -> ECS -> END.

When the Lambda function fails, it returns an exception as the Step Function failure cause. However, for the ECS Fargate task, it only returns container status params, information about latest status etc.
I am wondering, is it possible to get CloudWatch logs of Fargate task into Step Functions?
I have activated  the "Wait for task to complete" option in step function to wait until fails. But still getting container status parameters as a failed logs.
I also checked "Wait for Callback" option to update this task from ECS Fargate job, but we don't want to touch source code of ECS.
Failed logs example
